# swift: TableViewCell doesn't update constraints until scrolling

Tags: swift

i have a tableviewCell containing 2 labels. 
The right one has a fixed width and fixed trailing space to superview  and the left one a fixed leading space to superview and trailing to right label.
Sometimes i only need the the left label and in this case i want the left one to have a fixed trailing space to superview instead. So, i created a second inactive constraint and do this in my code:

```
if(entry.right.isEmpty) {
    tableCell?.longConstraint.isActive = true
    tableCell?.shortConstraint.isActive = false        
    tableCell?.rightLabel.isHidden = true
} else {
    tableCell?.longConstraint.isActive = false
    tableCell?.shortConstraint.isActive = true
    tableCell?.rightLabel.isHidden = false
}
```

but when i load the table all displayed cells have the default constraint active and only after scolling out of view and in again, they are displayed correctly.

Comment: Try tableCell.layoutIfNeed()

Answer (score 0):

For an easy way you can embed them inside a horizontal `UIStackview` and set

```
self.rightlb.isHidden = true
```

and it will disappear with no width automatically , also in your current code make sure

```
tableCell?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

after you change the constraints

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code after adjusting constraints programmatically

```
tableCell?.setNeedsLayout()
tableCell?.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hope this works